# Why can Gem install gems debase and ruby-debug-ide but Bundler cannot?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I can process this Gemfile with the gem utility but not with the bundler.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'debase', '0.2.5.beta2'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.7.3'
```

These commands demonstrate the problem.

Gem:

```
docker run --rm -w /app -v `pwd`:/app ruby:3.1.1 gem install --file
```

Bundler:

```
docker run --rm -w /app -v `pwd`:/app ruby:3.1.1 bundle install
```

The bundler error:

```
Installing debase 0.2.5.beta2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/debase-0.2.5.beta2/ext
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
./siteconf20220329-1-ltcssn.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-3.1.1-p18 (revision 53f5fc4236a754ddf94b20dbb70ab63bd5109b18)
provided with
debase-ruby_core_source gem. Falling back to ruby-2.0.0-p645.
**************************************************************************
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
.
.
.
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/ruby-debug/debase/issues/95. Can you reproduce this issue on other ruby versions? 3.0? 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

In [readme gem debase](https://github.com/ruby-debug/debase#overview) is describe about this gem works with `ruby 2`. In your docker command you was using `Ruby 3`

To work in the moment use in your Gemfile `gem "debase", "0.2.5.beta2", require: false`

Comment: The Gemfile already referenced debase 0.2.5.beta2. Adding require: false does not change the outcome.